# JS addEventListener is not triggering

Tags: javascript, dom-events, bsmultiselect

When I add addEventListener in my JS file for 'change' it never triggers when an option is selected. If I add inline 'onchange' in my HTML it works but I prefer to use event listeners in my JS file.

Is there a specific way I need to add the event listener in my JS file?

Here is how I am adding the event listener:

```
var tagdropDown = document.getElementById("tagSelect");
    tagdropDown.addEventListener('change', function(){
        console.log("tag change");
        tagSelections = $('#tagSelect').val();
    }, false);
```

Comment: When are you calling the function, are you sure that your dropdown is definitely finished rendering at the time you're calling it?

Comment: I could edit your question, add basic html, and it works. I don't do that, because it would make the question seem silly. Can you maybe add the html you are using, to help reproduce the problem?

Comment: It has to do with the bsmultiselect plugin I am using. The above does work if I do not apply the plugin to the element. 

I am working on getting a working code snippet added with the plug to show the issue.

Comment: jquery plugin triggers only juqery event, try to subscribe to it with jquery `on` (it is not the same as dom events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used a JQuery subscription per Roman and it is working as needed now. Thanks! [Roman Pokrovskij](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506147/roman-pokrovskij)

jquery plugin triggers only juqery event, try to subscribe to it with jquery on (it is not the same as dom events). – Roman Pokrovskij

Comment: Still consider handling the setSelected (on bsMultiSelect configuration time) in most cases it should work better - you get changed option (but not an index).